# how to display ppt on webpage using html,php,js,dhtml?

Tags: html, dhtml

I am use the ifram & object in html.but not get appropriate output so give me appropriate answer for that, 
how to display ppt on webpage using html,js,php?

Answer (score 1):

There is no straight-forward way of embedding `.ppt` on your web page. A workaround would be using Google Docs. All you have to do is upload the presentation in Google Docs and get the link, then use it on your `iframe`

Example:

```
<iframe src="http://docs.google.com/gview?url=YOUR_WEBSITE_URL/PRESENTATION_FILE&embedded=true" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>
```